# How do I get a SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio driver to support microphone? 

Tags: 10.04, sound, drivers, alsa

The microphone is not working on UBUNTU, I checked ALSA mixer and i don't seem to have any channel muted.

I believe its a driver issue, since i already faced a lot of problems regarding driver support for this audio card.

Its ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit, and the kernal is Linux 2.6.32-27-generic

thanks for help.

Comment: What version of ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up, upgraded from Lucid to Maverick and it's now using the HDA_Creative driver instead of HD-Audio_Generic and so far it seems to be working!